# The specified file is an unrecognized or unsupported binary format

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I downloaded tutorial (0.3.8) from http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/, then according to instruction I used premake4.exe to builld visual studio 2010 projects (premake4 vs2010) and it works fine, but when I try to run some example, I get the error message

> The specified file is an unrecognized or unsupported binary format

[image]

can you tell me why?

Comment: you compiled the program as a library or you made the wrong project in your solution the main project.

Comment: The error message in the dialog seems to suggest that you're trying to execute a *library,* not an executable file.

Comment: so if I have: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B6152A72F2E0078!20461&authkey=!AHLuWq-q1sidwDc&v=3 how to start one of that tut* ?

Comment: Ok i got that, but now when I debug some project, only console shows for a second, not what I expected :( what I nead to do now?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio is a bit on the dumb side when it comes to debugging console applications. I cannot remember off the top of my head where this option is, but there is an option that defaults to disabled, that will tell the debugger to keep the console window open even after the application completes execution. Why they decided to set the default that way, I will never know - it makes it impossible to read any debug output that might have been written to stdout.

Comment: Yes, you can select with project shoud be executed, right click on project then properties. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you wrongly set the **.lib** project as your **startUp** project. Try to set your **.exe** project as your **startUp** project.

In **Visual studio** you can set a project into ***startUp*** project just by right click the **.exe** and select the option **"set as startUp project"**